# Prevent tox import from sources

Tags: pytest, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, tox

I have old Python packages using the *setuptools* `test` command that I want to migrate to *tox*.
These packages use a [flat layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/). I used to run the tests after installation in an isolated environment with a custom script.

When I run tests with *tox*, the imports are done from the source directories instead of the *tox* isolated virtual environment.
I tried the `toxworkdir` and `changedir` options but I still have the source directory in `sys.path`.

This is particularly problematic since I have compiled modules.

How can I do ?

Project layout looks like:

```
.
├── mymodule -> python code for mymodule
├── setup.py
├── src -> C++ code for extension
├── tests -> unittests
└── tox.ini
```

`setup.py`:

```py
_api = Extension(
    "mymodule._api",
    sources=("src/src1.cpp", ...)
)
setup(
    packages=["mymodule"],
    ext_modules=[_api],
    # ...
)
```

`tox.ini`:

```ini
[tox]
env_list = py{27,35,36,37,38,39,310,311,312}
minversion = 3.28

[testenv]
description = run the tests with pytest
package = wheel
wheel_build_env = .pkg
deps = pytest
commands = pytest {tty:--color=yes} tests
```

tox installs my package in:

`.tox/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mymodule/_api.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

But when I run the tests with `tox run` I have:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule._api'
```

Looking at `sys.path` it imports `mymodule` from the project directory instead of the virtual environment.

*tox* version is `4.4.7`.

Comment: Edit your question to show at least your project directory structure and your tox configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem related to **tox** but to [pytest import mechanisms](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/pythonpath.html).

**pytest** [searches for the top directory](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/7.3.1/src/_pytest/pathlib.py#L655) of the package going up the path as long as a `__init__.py` file exists. Then it alters `sys.path` to add that path. By default, the path is added at the first position, but you can configure the addition at the end.

According to the documentation, `--import-mode append` "*allows to run test modules against installed versions of a package*".

### Solution

```
[testenv]
changedir = tests
deps = pytest
commands = pytest {tty:--color=yes} --import-mode append
```

By removing the `__init__.py` files from the `tests` directory, we can remove the `--import-mode append` option.